# My program prints 0 as the Output all the time dispite that there are specific Words. I am trying to count the number of specif words in a document

Tags: java

Paste your source here:

Add new lines after "{" and before "}"
Add new lines before "{"
Remove empty lines.
Add comment lines before function.
Add new lines after ";"
Add new lines after "}" (For .css) (Thanks David)
Remove new lines (useful only if you add them again with the other functions above)
Add new lines after ";" but not in for loops (Don't check "Remove new lines" but do check "Remove empty lines")(Thanks Chris) (Experimental, uses a heuristic that might fail )
Add new lines after ";" but not in for loops and skip quotes (Don't check "Remove new lines" but do check "Remove empty lines") (Thanks Chris) (Experimental, uses a heuristic that might fail )
Reduce whitespace
Put the code again in the input box above after submit.
Skip HTML, give me plain code! (Use Save-As function of your browser)

```
import java.io.*;

public class CountingWords {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        int Count;

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""/home/dinesh/Documents/SD1/TextFile"))) {

            String ChkWord;

            String TargetWord = "A";

            Count = 0;

            while ((ChkWord = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if (ChkWord.contentEquals(TargetWord))

                Count++;               

            }

            System.out.println(Count++);

            in.close();

        }

    }

}
```

The file is found just it keeps printing Zero. I am a beginner in Java. Thank You

Comment: Do you have any line in your file that only contains `A`?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file you are reading?

Comment: I will repost Question sorry I made a mistake. This is the very first time I have used this website. It wont allow me till 90 minutes have passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing whether the entire line is equal to the word you are searching for.
this will only work if the file you are scanning has something like:

abcd
A
xyz

it would trigger then on A
but if you have
abcd A xyz
efg A qrs

then it will not match.
I think what you need is either regular expressions or use a loop that calls

```
int     indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

(initially fromIndex = 0, the next iteration of the loop use lastIndex + str.length()  or lastIndex + 1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the method contentEquals is used to compare a String with a StringBuffer,
as BufferedReader method readLine returns String, you should use method equals, in your case it would be something like:

```
ChkWord.equals(TargetWord);
```

Second and most important, lets assume you have a file that looks like:

```
A
Something A Vals
Another Example
A tree
```

every time the method readLine executes, it returns the entire line, what i mean is that the first time your loop acts it will return the String "A", in this case the comparison using method equals will be true and you will count the apparition of A. However the next iteration will return the String "Something A Vals", this time although there is an A, the comparison will return false because it is comparing "A" with "Something A Vals".
If you want to count that A in this sentence I recommend you read how to use StringTokenizer, that will help you to parse Strings according to a pattern like the blank space " " for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html